# Custom Accessory Button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessoryview

I am trying to add a custom button in the Accessory View for a UITableViewCell.

I have added the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {      
       // ....     
       let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
       button.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow-right-light.png")?.maskWithColor(color: .white), for: .normal)
       button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTest), for: .touchUpInside)
       button.tag = indexPath.row
       cell.accessoryView = button
       // ...
```

However, I don't see the button show up on in the Accessory View.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can think of two possible reasons:

- The problem might be that the button has no size, so it's invisible. Add this line, *after* setting the image:

  ```
  button.sizeToFit()
  ```
- Another possibility is that you have no image named `"arrow-right-light.png"`. That wouldn't crash your existing code, but it would prevent the button from having any image so you wouldn't see it. Try saying `UIImage(named: "arrow-right-light.png")!` instead, just as a test; if you crash, that was indeed the problem, and then you can figure out what the correct name is.

Comment: Thanks @matt. It was the size of the button.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for reporting back.

Comment: Leads to too small tappable area, in case image is smaller than 44x44 pt.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [@matt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49949213/1971013) above, but this makes the button as large as the image.

I showed a iOS builtin info image which is smaller than the [minimum advised button size of 44x44 points](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/).  Although the button works, it's hard(er) to tap; which is a common invisible UX issue seen in many apps (even professional ones.

Therefore instead of calling `button.sizeToFit()` you must set the buttons height (I did my full cell height of 50) and width to a nice & easy tappable 60.